# Using a Case statement IN where clause

Tags: mysql

Problem: When category= books & FMCG then shipping_cost less then selling_price else no check.. Please suggest..:)

Actual Condition:  WHERE
    a.shipping_cost < a.selling_price

Expected Condition: WHERE
    CASE WHEN a.category IN('Books','FMCG') then a.shipping_cost < a.selling_price END

Comment: you have two where clause. there should only be one where clause

Comment: 1 is actual & other one is expected

Comment: Are you using `mysql` or `vertica`?

Answer (score 0):

You could put it like that i think :

```
WHERE (a.category IN('Books','FMCG') AND a.shipping_cost < a.selling_price) OR 
  (a.category NOT IN('Books','FMCG'))
```